Read EEPROM via SPI (C232HM)
I want to read a M95128-DRMF4TG/K EEPROM with a C232Hm MPSSE cable, with contains a C232H MPSSE controller. This is my code (C#):
private void ReadSPI(byte[] byteArray, int adress) //adress is 0x0100, bytearray has 998 Elements for 998 bytes to read
{
    byte msbAdress = (byte)(adress >> 8);
    byte lsbAdress = (byte)adress;
    // First send the adress needed to the EEPROM
    byte[] eepromSendData = new byte[] //Sending the EEPROM the command, that it shall return the data from the specific adress
    {
        0x10, 0x02, 0x00,
        0x03, msbAdress, lsbAdress
    };
    ftStatus = ftdiDevice.Write(eepromSendData, eepromSendData.Length, ref bytesWritten);

    
    byte msbLength = ((byte)(byteArray.Length >> 8));
    byte lsbLength = (byte)byteArray.Length;
    
    byte[] readCommand = new byte[] // readCommand for the C232H controller
    {
        0x20, lsbLength, msbLength
    };
    ftStatus = ftdiDevice.Write(readCommand, readCommand.Length, ref bytesWritten);
    ftStatus = ftdiDevice.Read(byteArray, (uint)byteArray.Length, ref bytesRead);

    if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK || bytesRead != byteArray.Length)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error reading SPI");
        return;
    }
    bytesWritten = 0;
    bytesRead = 0;
}

My EEPROM returns only 0xFF for every byte.
Writing the readCommand is necessary, cause it activates the clock. Writing only ftdiDevice.Read will result in a freezing of the programm.
Reading different sections of the EEPROM ended in the same result.
The eepromSendData array, which commands the EEPROM tho send data from the adress in that array, gets to the EEPROM as it should. CS ist active. Clock can be measuered. The SOMI Pin is on 2.4V (Vcc is 3.3V) all the time, so as I see it, the EEPROM simply does not send any data.
Datasheet EEPROM

"sw1, sw2 and sw3 are stopwatches for debugging." - I'd leave them out here, it's just cluttering the code making it harder to read.

Where do you output the content of the read bytes? Are you using a breakpoint and the debugger?

Yes, I use the debugger and breakpoint

The output of my EEPROM ist High Impedance when not used, but it seems at it never changes from there to 0 or 1.

I am not sure if that (breakpoint) could be the problem, actually. Maybe try writing the received data out to console or a file, then inspect. Even if just to rule out, that this is the problem.

No, thats not the problem. Even without ony breaks, there is no signal on the SOMI line

Are you sure your measuring tool would be able to pick it up if it were sending data?

Yes I am sure. I am using an oscilloscope, I am detecting MOSI data and clock, I should be able to detect SOMI data. Even if I wouldn't be able to, the data should be in the byteArray

Hmmm, ok. So, ... what you are suspecting is that the EEPROM doesn't actually react correctly to your request, correct? Did you try another EEPROM? I've had hardware broken before that had perfectly fine readings on the pins but just didn't switch on the output pins.

Yeah that would be my guess. I just tried another one, that definitv works. Still the same problem

Found the problem. My coworker, who gave me the EEPROM, told me, that it contains data. But after searching for the root cause it was showed, that none of the EEPROM he gave me, contained data. Sry for the waste of time guys
